# How can you destroy a city in Civ 5 besides razing it or nuking it?

Tags: civilization-5

I just nuked a city twice and **destroyed it**.  I was unaware that it was possible to level a city completely...

Are there other methods of destroying a city completely besides razing it or nuking/a-bombing it to kingdom-come ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the nuke is the only military unit capable to destroying a city without taking it over and razing it. All other military units will take over the city and give you the option to raze it (With the exception of a capitol). So those are your only two options for destroying cities.

Not sure if nukes can destroy capitals as they don't take over the city.

Comment: Is this from testing? Or can you provide a source please?

Comment: This is from testing, abut I'll try and find a source to confirm.

Comment: Looked around a bit but can't find any source to confirm, although not found any mention of destroying a city in any other fashion.

Comment: You cannot destroy Capitals or Holy Cities(can't destroy a religion or prevent a Civ from being liberated)

Answer (score 0):

When you go onto the civilopedia, it claims that Nukes (not atomic bombs) are the only unit capable of destroying a city.